# update mysql record to add count when button on loop is clicked

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that displays candidates with their details using a mysql while loop and below each candidate is a "vote" button which is also inside the loop. I need to add 1count to a record when their button is clicked. My problem is the buttons inside the loop has the same names so they are all affected with the update even if only one is clicked.

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 

                $sql = "SELECT ename FROM election_title ORDER BY `sdate` ASC";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $ename= $row['ename'];
        ?> 
            <p><font size= "6px" align = "center" color = "#efbf77"> <?php echo $row['ename']. "<br>";?></p>
        <?php


            $sql = "SELECT * FROM candidate_list T1 INNER JOIN election_title T2 ON T1.ename = T2.ename WHERE T1.ename LIKE '%$row[ename]%';";
            $res = $conn->query($sql);
            if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
                while($rowval = $res->fetch_assoc())  {
                    $id= $rowval['id'];
                    $image_content= $rowval['image_content'];
                    $ename= $rowval['ename'];
                    $pos= $rowval['pos'];
                    $fname= $rowval['fname'];
                    $mname= $rowval['mname'];
                    $lname= $rowval['lname'];

        ?> 

                <div class = "cand">
                <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $rowval['image_content'] ) . '" width = "100%" height = "auto" />';?><?php echo "<p class = 'bold'>" .$rowval['fname']. " " .$rowval['mname']. " " .$rowval['lname'] . "</p>" .$rowval['pos']. "<br/>" .$rowval['pname'];?>
                 <form action="castvote.php" method="post">
                 <INPUT TYPE=submit NAME="<?php echo $fname; ?>" VALUE="<?php echo 'Vote ' .$fname; ?>">
                </div>
        <?php
        }
            } else {
            echo "No candidate(s) listed.";
        }

        ?>
        <?php
        }
            } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        ?>
```

And this is my query.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>NSDCI Voting System</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
    <?php
        $host = 'localhost';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = '';
        $db = 'voting_system';

        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);
        if($con)
        {

        $sql = "UPDATE candidate_list SET votes = votes +1 WHERE fname = $fname";
        $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        if($query)
        echo 'data inserted succesfully';
        }

            echo 'connected succesfully to the db!';

    ?>
```

How can i query a WHERE clause that matches my button name. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you updating the information using <input type="submit">? Can you share the code of your while loop with Vote button?

Comment: One way would be to assign, to each button, a `dataset` attribute - such as `data-id=$rowval['id']` and use javascript to read that dataset value and either send an ajax request or submit the form with that value. You would not need a form for every candidate - one form should suffice and change the value of a hidden field. The form itself, in your code, has no form elements which is peculiar

Comment: ...you should also look into [JOINS](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) in Mysql, instead of making queries inside the loop like that.

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi i wrote it completely above.

Comment: @RamRaider im new to php and have a very limited knowledge regarding ajax and javascript so...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i dont need to join two tables. Im troubled with calling the button in the mysql query(WHERE clause)

Comment: entering `1 or 1=1` for fname may also cause issues ;p

Comment: @LawrenceCherone "votes = votes + 1" so im getting the initial value of the votes then adding +1 on it. And i forgot to edit that out. Ive been testing queries in the WHERE clause

Comment: I see the increment, the sql injection is in the `fname` parameter, you need to use prepared query's.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone any idea on how can i call the looping VOTE button name in the WHERE clause?

Comment: Basically it is a voting system so i need to update the vote counts everytime a candidate's button is clicked.

Comment: It looks to me like you're giving your buttons NAME="something" attributes based on the `fname` column values from your query. You might find it helpful to look at `View Source...` for your generated page and see what you get.  I suspect `fname` is a string. You'll need to wrap it in quotes in your SQL statement in that case.

Comment: Pro tip: don't use `SELECT *` to retrieve result sets from `JOIN` statements in programs. If you have more than one column with the same name, the one php will retrieve is not predictable. Instead, list the columns you need in the query.  Pro tip 2: don't use a name where you can use a unique ID. I have a common surname, and it's a terrible unique identifier for a database update. (Maybe it's why I've never won an election for anything :-)

Comment: @O.Jones hahaha! If the voting system used in your elections is as bad as mine

Comment: @RamRaider i noticed it just now, i encountered aproblem with your code. Its not displaying the election title where the candidates belong in their header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to assign, to each button, a `dataset` attribute - such as `data-id=$rowval['id']` and use javascript to read that dataset value and either send an ajax request or submit the form with that value. You would not need a form for every candidate - one form should suffice and change the value of a hidden field.

Presumably `fname` means `forename` or `firstname` - if so then that is not a good item to use in your update statement, especially if the candidate's firstname is John for example where there a likely to be many. As each candidate in the db has his/her own ID it would make sense to use the ID for the update because that is guaranteed(?) to be unique.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>vote</title>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(e){
                var form=document.forms['vote'];
                var bttns=document.querySelectorAll('input.candidate');
                for( var n in bttns )if( bttns[ n ].nodeType==1 )bttns[ n ].addEventListener('click',function(e){
                    form['id'].value=this.dataset.id;
                    form.submit();
                }.bind(bttns[n]),false);
            },false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id='vote' action="castvote.php" method="post">
            <input type='hidden' name='id' />
        </form>

        <?php

            if ( $conn->connect_error )exit('unable to connect to database');
            /*
                not sure about the query but there should be no need to use nested queries in a loop
                when a join or a selection as below should suffice.
            */
            $sql="select * from `candidate_list` c 
                inner join `election_title` e on c.`ename` = e.`ename` 
                where c.`ename` in ( select distinct `ename` from `election_title` );";


            $res = $conn->query( $sql );
            if( $res->num_rows > 0 ) {

                while( $rs = $res->fetch_object() ){
                    $id=$rs->id;
                    $pos=$rs->pos;
                    $image=$rs->image_content;
                    $ename=$rs->ename;
                    $fname=$rs->fname;
                    $mname=$rs->mname;
                    $lname=$rs->lname;
                    $pname=$rs->pname;

                    echo "
                        <div class='cand'>
                            <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode( $image ) . "' />
                            <p class='bold'>
                                {$fname}{$mname}{$lname}
                            </p>{$pos}
                            <br/>
                            {$pname}
                            <input type='button' data-id='{$id}' class='candidate' value='Vote for {$fname}' />
                        </div>";
                }
            }

        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Using the above methodology would mean that the PHP code that updates the db needs to be changed to use the ID ( ie: $_POST['id'] )

```
$sql = "UPDATE candidate_list SET votes = votes+1 WHERE id='{$_POST['id']';";
```

I realise the code is vulnerable to sql injection - prepared statements is the way forward.

One thing I noticed after posting my answer was the `base64_encode( $image )` line - if this is coming from the db, as it is, then I guess that would be the path to the image rather than RAW data? If that is the case the line ought to read `base64_encode( file_get_contents( $image ) )`

In response to the valid comment about insecure code - how the use of prepared statements could be used to mitigate against sql inection.

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>NSDCI Voting System</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['id'] ) ){

                $dbhost =   'localhost';
                $dbuser =   'root'; 
                $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
                $dbname =   'voting_system';
                $db     =   new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

                $id=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

                $sql='update `candidate_list` set `votes` = `votes`+1 where `id`=?';
                $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

                if( $stmt && $id ){

                    $stmt->bind_param( 's', $id );
                    $result=$stmt->execute();

                    echo $result ? 'data inserted succesfully' : 'oops';
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will definitely try this! :)

Comment: That displaying of image is not a path, its a blob

Comment: ok - if the data in the db is a BLOB then ignore comment about `file_get_contents`

Comment: First thing to test, I would suggest, would be the sql query itself. Test in a gui - if it returns the results you would expect then the rest should be straightforward but remember none of the above was tested :(

Comment: Hey ram! I tried it in a new document and it worked! :) Now i just need to transfer it to my main code. Thanks fam!

Comment: None of that was tested? I saw just one minor error and thats a missing bracket, but all throughout, its awesome!

Comment: No, just wrote it in notepad - where was the missing bracket btw?

Comment: In the update query. In the latter part of your reply

$sql = "UPDATE candidate_list SET votes = votes+1 WHERE id='{$_POST['id']}';";

Comment: oh, I see it now...damn

Comment: But its ok. Im amazed

Comment: Ram, its me again. Is it possible to execute the php echo in the html form? Or convert it into a html code. For the sole purpose of applying my form's css to it

Comment: If you know it's open for SQL injections, why post it as is? Remember that many people simply copy/paste the code without reading every line in the answer (sure, it could be argued that it's up to them), but I don't that knowingly writing insecure code as an answer is a good idea. In this case, simply doing `(int) $_POST[''id']` (casting it as an integer) would solve the issue.

Comment: Generally because it was late and I was tired - but also because the main focus of my answer was on the mechanism involved to send a suitable value from the form rather than updating the db - however your point is noted and valid.

Answer (score 0):

I am changing the below part of your code.

```
<div class = "cand">
    <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($rowval['image_content'] ) . '" width = "100%" height = "auto" />';?><?php echo "<p class = 'bold'>" .$rowval['fname']. " " .$rowval['mname']. " " .$rowval['lname'] . "</p>" .$rowval['pos']. "<br/>" .$rowval['pname'];?>

    <form action="castvote.php" method="post">
        <INPUT TYPE=submit NAME="<?php echo $fname; ?>" VALUE="<?php echo 'Vote ' .$fname; ?>">
</div>
```

Try considering the idea of not using form. You can use a hyperlink with the action script. Pass the AutoIncrement value from the target table of the selected candidate via the URL. After this, fetch the value in your action script using `$_GET` and do the update. To ensure that the action script is not accessed directly, add the `isset($_GET)` validation. Below is the code.

```
<div class = "cand">
    <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($rowval['image_content'] ) . '" width = "100%" height = "auto" />';?><?php echo "<p class = 'bold'>" .$rowval['fname']. " " .$rowval['mname']. " " .$rowval['lname'] . "</p>" .$rowval['pos']. "<br/>" .$rowval['pname'];?>

    //I am changing your code here.

    <a href="castvote.php?id=<?php echo $auto_increment_value; ?>">Vote <php echo $fname; ?></a>
</div>
```

Now in your action script, use the below code.

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id_to_update = $_GET['id'];

    //Have your PHP update code here with the target id.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try this one :)

Comment: I changed my code with this
    
    <div class = "cand">
    <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $rowval['image_content'] ) . '" width = "100%" height = "auto" />';?><?php echo "<p class = 'bold'>" .$rowval['fname']. " " .$rowval['mname']. " " .$rowval['lname'] . "</p>" .$rowval['pos']. "<br/>" .$rowval['pname'];?>
      <br/>
      <a href="castvote.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Vote <?php echo $fname; ?></a>
     </div>

and query to this

if ($_GET['id']) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
   $sql = "UPDATE candidate_list SET votes = votes +1 WHERE id = $id";

Comment: So what is the outcome?

Comment: At first, when i didnt put a WHERE condition, it adds 1 to all records. And when i put the WHERE id = $id, its not adding to any records anymore. What could i be doing wrong?

Comment: To debug, simply follow, at least, two-step process. First step, disable your update code and simply print the fetched $id value to see if you are able to get the value to the action script. If yes, then there might be something wrong with your Update script. If not, let me know.

Comment: I tried, and its displaying "8". I have 7 records in my database. What do you think is it fetching?

Comment: You should have all the seven records displayed on the page with seven Vote links. Correct? If yes, are all the links showing 8? If yes, then there might be some problem with your fetched id from the DB.

Comment: So it is clear that now you just have to figure out the $id value fetched from the DB. The solution appears to be working. Waiting for your response.